# Input Date Object Step Up method in my Form that is Using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm currently trying to create a form that will extend on click using the method shown from this site. http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/domform.html

I have the Extending of the form more or less working fine, My issue is getting the Date field to correctly step up from the date that the user inputs in the first field.

Right now if I click on Add another Date, it adds a day to 1970-01-01 which i'm assuming is a default start date somewhere.

I'm not familiar enough with javascript to reference the generated date to the date that is initially selected by the User.

Here is a fiddle link of you want to see what I mean. https://jsfiddle.net/2nvz6kqj/9/

Note i'm pretty sure you can only get the date field to show up in Chrome correctly.

And here is my code.

```
 <script type="text/javascript">       

        var counter = 0;

        function moreFields() {
             var date = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
            counter++;
            var newFields = document.getElementById("readroot").cloneNode(true);
            newFields.id = '';
            newFields.style.display = 'block';
            var newField = newFields.childNodes;
            for (var i=0;i<newField.length;i++) {
                var theName = newField[i].name;
                if (theName)
                    newField[i].name = theName + counter;
            }
            var insertHere = document.getElementById("writeroot");
            insertHere.parentNode.insertBefore(newFields,insertHere);
            document.getElementById("myDate").stepUp(1);

        }

        window.onload = moreFields;

    </script>

<body>
    <div id="readroot" style="display: none">

        <input type="button" value="Remove Date"
               onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /><br /><br />

        <input type="date" id="myDate" value="">

        <select name="rankingsel">
            <option>School Day</option>
            <option value="day1">Day 1</option>
            <option value="day2">Day 2</option>
            <option value="day3">Day 3</option>
            <option value="day4">Day 4</option>
            <option value="day5">Day 5</option>
            <option value="closed">School Closed</option>
        </select><br /><br />



    </div>

    <form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/show_params.cgi">

        <span id="writeroot"></span>

        <input type="button" onclick="moreFields()" value="Add Another Date" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send form" />

    </form>
</body>
```

Ultimately once i get this working correctly, I'll submit it to a DB with PHP.

Comment: on jsFiddle, you need to remove your <script> tag from the HTML frame and move your JS to the JavaScript frame.

Comment: also, remove the <body> tags from your HTML in jsFiddle; those are added to the result frame automatically

Comment: Yeah, for what ever reason doing it the right way is breaking what I did and nothing displays, which is the reason I decided to leave everything under the html window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I changed a few things, but this should work for you.

**NOTE:** In order to keep the code and markup close to what you had, I didn't "fix" some of the JavaScript and HTML that I consider to be bad practice.

I also took some liberties with the readroot element IDs and writeroot is now a DIV not a SPAN as you had it.

```
<html>
<head>

    <script type="text/javascript">       

        var counter = 0;
        var date = new Date();

        // this function adds a day to the date variable
        function addDay (dateObj) {
            var ticks = dateObj.getTime();
            var newTicks = ticks + (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);
            dateObj.setTime(newTicks);
        }

        function moreFields() {
            //var dateVal = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
            counter++;

            // querySelector is nicer way to get your elements
            var newFields = document.querySelector("#readroot").cloneNode(true);
            newFields.id = newFields.id + counter;
            newFields.style = null;

            // nifty way to convert node list into an array
            var fields = Array.prototype.slice.call(newFields.childNodes);

            // now use forEach instead of old-style for loop
            fields.forEach(function (f,i,nodes) {
                var theName = f.name;
                if (theName) {
                    f.id = theName + counter;
                }
            });

            // convert "writeroot" to div and just append the newFields container
            var form = document.querySelector('#writeroot');
            form.appendChild(newFields);

            // to set the date, you need to use an ISO-format date string
            var dateFields = form.querySelectorAll('[name="myDate"]');
            var len = dateFields.length;
            var dateField = dateFields[len - 1];
            if (dateField) {
                var dateISO = date.toISOString().substr(0,10);
                dateField.value = dateISO;
                addDay(date);    
            }
        }

        window.onload = moreFields;

    </script>

</head>
<body>
    <div id="readroot" style="display: none">

        <input type="button" value="Remove Date"
               onclick="this.parentNode.parentNode.removeChild(this.parentNode);" /><br /><br />

        <input type="date" name="myDate">

        <select name="rankingsel">
            <option>School Day</option>
            <option value="day1">Day 1</option>
            <option value="day2">Day 2</option>
            <option value="day3">Day 3</option>
            <option value="day4">Day 4</option>
            <option value="day5">Day 5</option>
            <option value="closed">School Closed</option>
        </select><br /><br />



    </div>

    <form method="post" action="/cgi-bin/show_params.cgi">
        <div id="writeroot"></div>            

        <input type="button" onclick="moreFields()" value="Add Another Date" />
        <input type="submit" value="Send form" />

    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The date variable will always start with the current date. If you need to change that, just pass in a new date value like so: new Date('7/4/2015')

Comment: Thank you so much Silkster,  And another thank you for commenting out your solution its a great help to someone who is trying to learn JS.